# Auto Increment Between Tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms

I have two tables **book** and **gbook**. The srtucture is the same in both;

```
id   title   author   isbn   year
```

I then have two web forms on two different php pages that send data to the corresponding tables - '**Book Form**' and '**G Book Form**'.

When I submit 'Book Form' the book table id increments successfully, likewise when I submit 'G Book Form' the gbook table id increments. But, how do I set my tables up in such a way that the id's are joined/shared between the two tables? Meaning, the id will auto increment from wherever the last form insert left off.

The reason I would like to do this (as well as not understanding the best approach) is because my 'Book Form' allows users to manually add book info. Whereas the 'G Book Form' auto populates the book info using the Google Books Api.

Ideally I would like my *book* table to be something like;

```
id
1
2
4
5
8
9
```

And the *gbook* table to be something like;

```
id
3
6
7
```

Quite new to php/mysql here so any advice or direction is appreciated. I can provide existing code if necessary.

Comment: Why yould you want to do that? Features being not supported are a good sign of not doing it.

Comment: Updated with a reason, again quite new to this so appreciate the comment.

Comment: Other databases such as Oracle, SQL Server, Postgres etc have definable sequences that you can apply to any table but as far as I'm aware MySQL does not. Other than running a stored procedure that checks the maximum value of one table, then the other I'd imagine the best solution would be to put them both on the one table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way you'll have will probably be to put them in the same table, with a special column specifying which type of book it is.

Comment: This works, I have created a new column which adds a 'g' or 'm' respectively.

Answer (score 4):

An **alternative** may help. Put all the data in the **one table** adding one extra column (FK) and create **another table** consisting type of books.

**tbl_books**

```
id   booktype_id   title   author   isbn   year
```

**tbl_booktypes**

```
id   type
```

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to achieve this through php. You will have to run an alter query every time there is a change in one of the table. For eg:
If you are inserting value into the book table you get the increment ID of that table using `mysql_insert_id()` and use it in the alter query.

```
    $id = mysql_insert_id() + 1;
    ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT= $id;
```

Though this approach is not recommended and not a standard practice.

Answer (score 1):

An another idea:

Disable the auto incrementaion from both tables. Use the SQL command `MAX(iD)` to read the biggest value from both tables and increment the result:

`Select MAX(iD) From Book Form` and store it into a variable. Then execute `Select MAX(iD) from G Book Form` store it either. Compare both values and increment it by one.

And though, in my eyes the best idea comes from blue112. It is sometimes a good idea to generalise your sheme of database.